# GTM - Track links per section, per page

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've pretty much spent all day configuring GTM (it takes forever) but I'm facing a situation which I don't know how to track:

Lets say there are many links, on many pages, they all have a *url* like this `/xxx/yyy/zzz`.
only `zzz` is changing. I have these links in different sections on the website.

When a user **clicks** a link I need to know what **section** and what **page** was this link DOM element was at. (or in GTM only target clicks for links in a **specific** section)

### Example markup for homepage

```
<section class='A'>
    <a href='/xxx/yyy/1'>link</a>
    <a href='/xxx/yyy/2'>link</a>
    <a href='/xxx/yyy/3'>link</a>
</section>
<section class='B'>
    <a href='/xxx/yyy/1'>link</a>
    <a href='/xxx/yyy/2'>link</a>
    <a href='/xxx/yyy/3'>link</a>
</section>
```

I've read [google's instructions](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/3420054?hl=en#ClicksOnLinks) carefully but they don't explain how to set up specific tracking, they only talk about general all-purpose tracking.

I don't want to use `dataLayer.push()` but I want the GTM system to handle everything for me, without changing the website code.

---

I would imagine GTM has some sort of event-delegated capabilities which could be used as rules to track links only on specific places, so more specific rules could be created.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of GTM you are using the terminology and steps might be different, but I'll outline how to handle this.

Set up an auto event macro named parentClass (or something simialr) to return the class of the parent element of the clicked element.

Set up a Link Click Listener to fire on all pages if you haven't already.

Set up a Google Analytics Event tag in GTM. Use the parentClass macro as the event label.

Set up a rule that fires when the GA Event tag when the URL contains the pattern you're looking for.

There are other ways to set this up and you may need to capture additional information, but this should get you going.